# Possible memory error in the code and possible solution?

Tags: c, regex, valgrind

The source code given below is a cut-down version of some more detailed C source code that parses input strings to see if they match pre-determined patterns. The code attempts to parse an input string (which you can assume is a valid null-terminated string). If
the string contains a valid unsigned integer the function returns 0, otherwise it returns an error −1. An unsigned integer matches the regex ˆ[0-9]+$.

I tried to run the valgrind command to find out the possible error which displayed the following output( which I am not able to understand).

```
==15269== 
==15269== Invalid read of size 1
==15269==    at 0x400770: parse_exact (assign2b.c:23)
==15269==    by 0x400957: xtz_parse_unsigned (assign2b.c:82)
==15269==    by 0x400A26: test_parse_unsigned (assign2b.c:102)
==15269==    by 0x400B06: main (assign2b.c:128)
==15269==  Address 0x51f2045 is 0 bytes after a block of size 5 alloc'd
==15269==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15269==    by 0x4EBAD81: strdup (strdup.c:43)
==15269==    by 0x400AF1: main (assign2b.c:127)
==15269== 
==15269== Invalid read of size 1
==15269==    at 0x400770: parse_exact (assign2b.c:23)
==15269==    by 0x400957: xtz_parse_unsigned (assign2b.c:82)
==15269==    by 0x400A26: test_parse_unsigned (assign2b.c:102)
==15269==    by 0x400B9B: main (assign2b.c:142)
==15269==  Address 0x51f2135 is 0 bytes after a block of size 5 alloc'd
==15269==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==15269==    by 0x400B72: main (assign2b.c:140)
```

Given below is the code. Kindly tell the errors in the code and possible solution and how the same can be deduced using the valgrind

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define OK 9999
    #define EOS '\0'
    #define XT_SUCCESS 0
    #define XT_FAIL -1

    typedef int (*PARSE_FUNC)(const char *s, const char **endptr);

    static int parse_exact(const char *s, const char **endptr, PARSE_FUNC pfunc)
    {
        const char *cp = s;
        int c;
        int state = 1;
        while (state != XT_SUCCESS && state != XT_FAIL)
        {
            c = *cp++;  // nextchar
            switch(state)
            {
            case 1:
                state = pfunc(--cp, endptr);
                cp = *endptr;
                if (state == XT_SUCCESS) state = 2;
                else cp++;  // on FAIL jump ahead to get undone on exit
                break;
            case 2:
                if (EOS == c) state = OK;
                else state = XT_FAIL;
                break;
            case OK:
                state = XT_SUCCESS;
                break;
            default:
                /* LOGIC ERROR */
                assert(0==1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (endptr) 
            *endptr = --cp;
        return state;
    }

    static int base_unsigned(const char *s, const char **endptr)
    {
        const char *cp = s;
        int c;
        int state = 1;
        while (state != XT_SUCCESS && state != XT_FAIL)
        {
            c = *cp++;  // getnextchar
            switch(state)
            {
            case 1:
                if (isdigit(c)) state = 2;
                else state = XT_FAIL;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (isdigit(c)) state = 2;
                else state = XT_SUCCESS;
                break;
            default:
                /* LOGIC ERROR */
                assert(0==1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (endptr) 
            *endptr = --cp;
        return state;
    }

    int xtz_parse_unsigned(const char *s, const char **endptr)
    {
        PARSE_FUNC pfunc = base_unsigned;
        return parse_exact(s, endptr, pfunc);
    }

    void xt_pr_error(int status, const char *s, const char *endptr)
    {
        if (0 != status)
        {
            if (endptr[0])
                printf("ERROR: '%c' at position %d is not allowed", *endptr, (endptr - s)+1);
            else if ((endptr - s) > 0)
                printf("ERROR: cannot end with '%c'", endptr[-1]);
            else
                printf("ERROR: value is empty");
        }
    }

    void test_parse_unsigned(const char *s, int expected)
    {
        int status;
        const char *endptr; // Ptr to first invalid character
        status = xtz_parse_unsigned(s, &endptr);
        printf("Test input='%s' status=%d ", s, status);
        xt_pr_error(status, s, endptr);
        if (status != expected)
            printf(" NOT EXPECTED!\n");
        else
            printf(" (OK)\n");
    }


    int main(void)
    {
        char s1234[] = "1234";
        char s12a4[] = "12a4";
        char *ptr;

        // Tests with string literals
        test_parse_unsigned("1234", XT_SUCCESS);
        test_parse_unsigned("12a4", XT_FAIL);

        // Tests with static strings arrays
        test_parse_unsigned(s1234, XT_SUCCESS);
        test_parse_unsigned(s12a4, XT_FAIL);

        // Tests using strdup()
        ptr = strdup("1234");
        test_parse_unsigned(ptr, XT_SUCCESS);
        free(ptr);

        ptr = strdup("123a");
        test_parse_unsigned(ptr, XT_FAIL);
        free(ptr);

        ptr = strdup("1a34");
        test_parse_unsigned(ptr, XT_FAIL);
        free(ptr);

        // Test using malloc and strcpy()
        ptr = malloc(5);
        strcpy(ptr, "1234");
        test_parse_unsigned(ptr, XT_SUCCESS);
        free(ptr);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please indicate where `assign2b.c:23` is.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from your code where the real error is, you'd have to go through it with a debugger. But from the look of it, read of 1 byte beyond, your strings are not properly null terminated or you don't handle that condition well.

The function that valgrind points to is a bit difficult to grasp, because you don't have an explicit condition for the end of the string, that is when `c` is `'\0'`.

Also:

Things like `*cp++` belong into a museum, don't use expressions for their side effects. Here instead of a `while` loop you could easily have a `for` loop with `cp` as iteration variable

```
for (const char *cp = s;
     state != XT_SUCCESS && state != XT_FAIL;
     ++cp) {
    ...
}
```

Your mixture of using your state variable with named constants and numbers is insane and unreadable for others or for yourself if you come back a week later

Answer (score 0):

In function `parse_exact`, you are reading one position beyond EOS. In detail, this is what happens when you reach the end of the input string:

```
c = *cp++;  // nextchar
```

reads a NUL character (`EOS`).

```
if (EOS == c) state = OK;
```

Because state is neither `XT_SUCCESS` nor `XT_FAIL`, another pass is made through the loop.

```
c = *cp++;  // nextchar
```

reads the character beyond `EOS`. On some systems, this is accepted, but with strict bounds checking, it is not. In your case, an error occurs.

```
case OK:
    state = XT_SUCCESS;
```

So eventually, `state` would have become `XT_SUCCESS`. Makes me wonder why you have this intermediate state of `OK`.

I suggest you abandon `OK`, and replace it by `XT_SUCCESS` in this line of code:

```
if (EOS == c) state = OK;
```